# easy_install -U rospkg runs infinetly on debian bifferboard

Tags: debian

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to install ros on a bifferboard running debian squeeze. I had the same problem also with lenny and electric. The bifferboard is a small board running a 486 compatible CPU as 140 MHz.
I followed the tutorial on http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Debian and the first few steps work, but easy_install always freezes. I can have it running for a week, and it just uses the CPU and only a small amount of memory.

bifferboard:~# easy_install -U rospkg
install_dir /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/
Searching for rospkg
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/rospkg/
Reading http://www.ros.org/wiki/rospkg
Reading http://pr.willowgarage.com/downloads/rospkg/
Best match: rospkg 1.0.4
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/r/rospkg/rospkg-1.0.4.tar.gz#md5=0907fe3718df1d1cb2c3a1156597089a
Processing rospkg-1.0.4.tar.gz
Running rospkg-1.0.4/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-tHbVyH/rospkg-1.0.4/egg-dist-tmp-nuBLnz
****** running endlessly ******************

bifferboard:~# pip install -U rosinstall vcstools rospkg rosdep
Requirement already up-to-date: rosinstall in /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/rosinstall-0.6.17-py2.6.egg
Requirement already up-to-date: vcstools in /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/vcstools-0.1.17-py2.6.egg
Requirement already up-to-date: rospkg in /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages
Downloading/unpacking rosdep
Downloading rosdep-0.9.5.tar.gz (61Kb): 61Kb downloaded
Running setup.py egg_info for package rosdep
****** running endlessly ******************

How could I debug this further?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36538/easy_install--u-rospkg--runs-infinetly-on-debian-bifferboard/) by [ulrichard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1774/ulrichard/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2012-06-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A guy from pip showed me how I could work around the problem, but he suggested, that it's bad practice for a package to try to import so much of itself from within setup.py.
https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/588

That got me one step further. Now I have the same behavior with rosinstall. The following command ran for a couple of hours today without making any progress:

```
#rosinstall --catkin ~/ros-underlay http://ros.org/rosinstalls/fuerte-ros-base.rosinstall
```

When I terminated it with ctrl-c, I got something like a call stack:

```
    ^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/rosinstall", line 5, in <module>
    pkg_resources.run_script('rosinstall==0.6.17', 'rosinstall')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 467, in run_script
    self.require(requires)[0].run_script(script_name, ns)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 1200, in run_script
    execfile(script_filename, namespace, namespace)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/rosinstall-0.6.17-py2.6.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/rosinstall", line 5, in <module>
    from rosinstall.rosinstall_cli import rosinstall_main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/rosinstall-0.6.17-py2.6.egg/rosinstall/rosinstall_cli.py", line 53, in <module>
    import yaml
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/yaml/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from loader import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/yaml/loader.py", line 8, in <module>
    from constructor import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/yaml/constructor.py", line 161, in <module>
    class SafeConstructor(BaseConstructor):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/yaml/constructor.py", line 257, in SafeConstructor
    inf_value *= inf_value
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Running htop in another session suggests otherwise, but could that have to do with the limited resources of the device, or are these general problems?

---

Originally posted by [ulrichard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1774/ulrichard/) with karma: 36 on 2012-06-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-06-27**:
Thanks for the update. I've ticketed it at: https://github.com/ros/rosdep/issues/11 and https://github.com/ros/rospkg/issues/2